# How to Append html code inside dialog using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, dialog

I have this variable `template="<div>...</div>"`

I want show this html code inside a dialog:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p id="templates"></p>
</div>

<script>
    $("#templates").html(template);
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
       height: auto,
       width: 800,
       modal: true,
       // ...
    });
</script>
```

But it doesn't work.

How I can append my custom html inside a dialog?

Comment: You are trying to add `"<html><head>...</head></html>"` into `<p>`. Are you serious? You can use `<iframe>` for this. Or maybe more simplified (just `<body>` inner HTML) template and `<div>` instead of `<p>`.

Comment: "I have this variable template="<html><head>...</head></html>"

I want show this html code inside a dialog:"

No, you don't want that. I think you've misunderstood what you're trying to accomplish a bit.

Comment: @Regent I am wrong...thx...;)!!!

Answer (score 2):

This should work for your purposes:

```
function PopModal(StuffToAppearInModal) {
              $('<div>' + StuffToAppearInModal+ '</div>').dialog({
              height: auto,
              width: 800,
              modal: true,
                });
            }
```

remove the "head" and "html" tags from your variable, and call it like this:

```
 PopModal("hey this is going to appear in my <font color='Red'>modal</font>.  html controls work, too like this: <input type='text' id='tbTest'/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wireframes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Website_wireframe) or append code without `<html><head>...</head></html>` because it is determined as web page.

Answer (score 0):

Only valid html content will be interpreted as parameter inside html function. If not, it will be filtered. In your example filter only leaves "..." in your content.

See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Kaster/KmXKE/) for other (valid) html content.

```
var template="<table style=\"border:solid red 2px;\"><tr><td><u>Test</u></td></tr></table>";
$("#templates").html(template);
...
```